# Im trying to loop through a recordset of class numbers to then query supplies from another recordset using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, recordset

I have these recordsets an I'm faking a $_POST in between the queries to use a values from the first query to get values from the second query, in this manner I get the first row of many, I've tried a foreach loop in-between the queries and fail...

How do I loop through the first recorset rows as many are returned?.... the code is:

```
$maxRows_rs_all_classes = 50;
$pageNum_rs_all_classes = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_rs_all_classes'])) {
  $pageNum_rs_all_classes = $_GET['pageNum_rs_all_classes'];
}
$startRow_rs_all_classes = $pageNum_rs_all_classes * $maxRows_rs_all_classes;

mysql_select_db($database_conn_studiogear_mgr, $conn_studiogear_mgr);
$query_rs_all_classes = "SELECT sg_class_desc.class_image,    
                                sg_class_desc.class_location,
                                sg_classes.class_name,
                                sg_class_desc.class_room,
                                sg_classes.class_cat1,
                                sg_classes.class_cat2,
                                sg_classes.class_cat3,
                                sg_classes.class_id 
                         FROM sg_class_desc   
                             INNER JOIN sg_classes 
                                   ON sg_class_desc.class_id = sg_classes.class_id";

$query_limit_rs_all_classes = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", 
                                        $query_rs_all_classes,
                                        $startRow_rs_all_classes, 
                                        $maxRows_rs_all_classes);

$rs_all_classes = mysql_query($query_limit_rs_all_classes, $conn_studiogear_mgr) 
                           or die (mysql_error());

$row_rs_all_classes = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_all_classes);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_rs_all_classes'])) {
    $totalRows_rs_all_classes = $_GET['totalRows_rs_all_classes'];
} else {
    $all_rs_all_classes = mysql_query($query_rs_all_classes, $conn_studiogear_mgr);
    $totalRows_rs_all_classes = mysql_num_rows($all_rs_all_classes);
}
$totalPages_rs_all_classes = ceil($totalRows_rs_all_classes/$maxRows_rs_all_classes)-1;

$_POST['class_id'] = $row_rs_all_classes['class_id'];

//without the following loop I return the first row and the second query works for the first row
// start loop when I use this loop, "Array" is echoed out and next query does not run
$classes = $row_rs_all_classes['class_id']; // from recordset above
foreach ($classes as $value) {
    $ArrayClasses[] = "".$value  ."";
    echo $ArrayClasses; //
}
// end loop
$colname_rs_gear = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['class_id'])) {
  $colname_rs_gear = $_POST['class_id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_conn_prestashop, $conn_prestashop);
$query_rs_gear = sprintf("SELECT ps_product_lang.name, 
                                 ps_product.id_product,  
                                 ps_product.price,
                                 ps_product.reference,
                                 ps_product_lang.description_short,
                                 ps_product_lang.description,
                                 ps_supplier.name,
                                 sg_class_gear.class_gear_image,
                                 sg_class_gear.class_gear_product_link 
                         FROM ps_product 
                            INNER JOIN ps_product_lang
                              ON ps_product.id_product = ps_product_lang.id_product   
                            INNER JOIN ps_supplier
                              ON ps_product.id_supplier = ps_supplier.id_supplier   
                            INNER JOIN sg_class_gear
                              ON sg_class_gear.class_gear_pid = ps_product.id_product 
                         WHERE ps_product.id_product = sg_class_gear.class_gear_pid 
                           AND sg_class_gear.class_id = %s",
                      GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_gear, "int"));

$rs_gear = mysql_query($query_rs_gear, $conn_prestashop) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_gear = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_gear);
$totalRows_rs_gear = mysql_num_rows($rs_gear);
```

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 1):

1) You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

2) You are using an obsolete database library (mysql) and should switch to mysqli or PDO

3) mysql_fetch_*() functions return a **SINGLE** row of data from the result set. Since you're not calling mysql_fetch_in a loop for your initial query, you only ever get the first row of results. Your code should be

```
$result = mysql_query($first_query_sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $result2 = mysql_query($inner_query_sql);
      while($row2 = ...) {
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc B, I only posted the queries, not the entire SQL, I do have injectin covered... thanks for suggestion. The site is a bit dated and This is what I have to Work with.